# json-server : how to do complex queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-server

I have a set of users each with a team id.

I have a set of records which are 'owned' by a user.

e.g.

```
users: [
{ id: 1, teamId: 1234 },
...
],
records: [
{ id: 1, usersId: 1 },
....
]
```

Can I issue an API call to json-server that either

1. gets all records owned by users with a specific teamid?

   `/records?users.teamId=1234`

   According to the [API guide](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#filter) I've found, this should work but doesn't. Adding `_expand=users` onto the query does seem to show the tables are linked.
2. alternatively gets all records if I provide a list of userids to filter on?

   `/records?usersId=[1,2,3,4]`

Is there any complete documentation on what you can do on the json-server API?